# MySQL COUNT() across multiple columns

Tags: mysql, count

I have been banging my head over this one for quite a while now but can not seem to get it working :(

I have a table which among other standard fields, also has a few fields for different values of a same kind (INT for example). Value of each field is unique -> meaning if it appears in a `val_1` it will not appear in `val_2` and `val_n`. It can be however repeated in next row. My table looks something like this:

```
| id | val_1 | val_2 | val_3 | ... | val_n | some other stuff | ... |
```

My question is: How can I count occurrences of certain values in my table? For example: I would like to know which value occurs the most.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT val_1) AS val_1_count,
  COUNT(DISTINCT val_2) AS val_2_count,
  ...
FROM ...
```

will give you the counts for each field.

```
SELECT val_1, count(*) as val_1_count
FROM ...
GROUP BY val_1
```

will give you the counts for a value. You can use UNION to repeat this for val_1 to val_n in a single (kludgy) query.

If you want the counts over all fields, you need

```
SELECT val,count(*) as valcount
FROM (
  SELECT val_1 AS val FROM ...
  UNION ALL
  SELECT val_2 AS val FROM ...
  ...
) AS baseview
GROUP BY val
```

Comment: The count over all fields was very helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: i'm stuck in similar situation for a day.
I need to get all the rows that have duplicate values in different columns. like if row0 val_1 is same as row2_val_2, i need row 0 and row 2. and all other rows as well fulfilling the criteria

Comment: @saad This seems to be quite different (and much more demanding of DB performance), are we talking of only 2 columns? Should be solvable as `SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id IN (SELECT t1.id FROM tablename AS t1 INNER JOIN tablename AS t2 ON t1.val_1=t2.val_2 OR t1.val_2=t2.val_1)`

Comment: thanks for the great help.
my requirement is a bit more complex.
I have a table with 15 cols. 3 cols are val_1, val_2 and val_3 which contain some MAC addresses. Now, i am provided a list of MAC addresses, and i need to find all the rows that contain any of the MAC present in the list, such that a MAC address exist at least twice in the table. p.s. Within a row, val_1, val_2 and val_3 will never have same value.
Really appreciating your help.

Comment: @saad This is just an easy extension to my last comment: `SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id IN (SELECT t1.id FROM tablename AS t1 INNER JOIN tablename AS t2 ON t1.val_1=t2.val_2 OR t1.val_2=t2.val_1 OR  t1.val_1=t2.val_3 OR t1.val_3=t2.val_1 OR t1.val_3=t2.val_2 OR t1.val_2=t2.val_3)`

Comment: Actually `SELECT t1.* FROM tablename AS t1 INNER JOIN tablename AS t2 ON t1.val_1=t2.val_2 OR t1.val_2=t2.val_1 OR  t1.val_1=t2.val_3 OR t1.val_3=t2.val_1 OR t1.val_3=t2.val_2 OR t1.val_2=t2.val_3` is enough. no need for the subquery

Comment: i believe im almost there. 
I tried adding WHERE `val_1` IN ('targetValue1','targetValue2') OR `val_2` IN ('targetValue1','targetValue2') OR `val_3` IN ('targetValue1','targerValue2') in the end of the query, since i need to hunt for only a required list of target MACs. It is returning me an error: 'val_1' in where clause is ambiguous
what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: you need to qualify: `WHERE t1.val_1 IN ('targetValue1','targetValue2') OR t1.val_2 IN ('targetValue1','targetValue2') OR t1.val_3 IN ('targetValue1','targerValue2')` (mind the **t1.**)

Comment: You are so the man @EugenRieck ... Can't thank you enough. Finally got it working.
This is my final query statement:
SELECT t1.* 
FROM (sensors AS t1 INNER JOIN sensors AS t2 ON
t1.val_1=t2.val_2 OR
t1.val_2=t2.val_1 OR
t1.val_1=t2.val_3 OR
t1.val_3=t2.val_1 OR
t1.val_3=t2.val_2 OR
t1.val_2=t2.val_3 OR
t1.val_1=t2.val_1 OR
t1.val_2=t2.val_2 OR
t1.val_3=t2.val_3)
WHERE
t1.val_1 in ('08:17:35:82:63:41','08:17:35:82:63:4d',) OR
t1.val_2 in ('08:17:35:82:63:41','08:17:35:82:63:4d',) OR
t1.val_3 in ('08:17:35:82:63:41','08:17:35:82:63:4d',)
GROUP BY t1.val_1, t1.val_2, t1.val_3