# MySQL multiple GROUP BY columns into one column

Tags: mysql

I have query about Group By in Mysql

Looks like my table
col1 and col2

1    1
   4    6
   5    4
   2    3
   1    9
   2    1
   3    2

Need to display the output like this

### col1&col2 and  count(col1&col2)

```
1   4
2   3
3   2
4   2
5   1
6   1
9   1
```

can any one suggest to get the above result as output using mysql query?

Thanks in advance

Comment: your "would like" sample makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: You mean - count in 2 colums? Like '1' is present 4 times, so it's 4. '2' occur 3 times, so it's 3. Right? Does order important for you?

Comment: Have a look here-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574093/mysql-count-across-multiple-columns

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT some_table.col, count(some_table.col)
FROM 
(
SELECT col1 as col FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT col2 as col FROM table
)  AS some_table
GROUP BY col
```

Something like this - [MySQL COUNT() multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625212/mysql-count-multiple-columns)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fff3d/5 fiddle for good measure, you beat me to it while I was building this

Comment: Thanks to @Gilberg, table alias is required.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT my_table.col, count(my_table.col)
FROM 
(
   SELECT col1 as col FROM your_table
   UNION ALL
   SELECT col2 as col FROM your_table
) AS my_table
GROUP BY col
```

Don't forget the table names and you have to have a table alias.  I tried to make this a comment but didn't have enough points to comment.  Just an addendum to @tigran

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solution with the help of you all

SELECT col, count(col) FROM (
    SELECT col1 as col FROM table_name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT col2 as col FROM table_name
)  AS temp_table
GROUP BY col
ORDER BY col

Thanks to all of you @ Marc B, @Tigran, @serakfalcon and @Gilberg