# how to count number of occurences of some values in a mysql row?

Tags: mysql

i have a code and can't figure how to count the number of occurences of the values, for example what is the total of "c"'s. numbers in db are tooth numbers and x means lack of tooth, c is caries and w is filling.

```
 SELECT SUM(18='w'+17='w'+16='w'+15='w'+14='w'+13='w'+12='w'+11='w'+21='w'+22='w'+23='w'+24='w'+25='w'+26='w'+27='w'+28='w'+48='w'+47='w'+46='w'+45='w'+44='w'+44='w'+43='w'+42='w'+41='w'+31='w'+32='w'+33='w'+34='w'+35='w'+36='w'+37='w'+38='w') AS liczbaw FROM badania
```

The table is like this:

[image]

Comment: you would do better off to show us the structure of your table and a few sample rows instead of what you have posted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL COUNT() across multiple columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574093/mysql-count-across-multiple-columns)

Comment: Try the last example from the answer on the possible duplicate link. (The one that uses UNION.)

Comment: Fix your broken schema design. See normalisation.

Answer (score 0):

First to note is however that probably you want to avoid having column names as numeric ... As per "[Can a number be used to name a MySQL table column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975417/can-a-number-be-used-to-name-a-mysql-table-column)", I have to quote with a back-tick (a backward quote).

I am actually not sure if you want to do this over multiple rows, but to aggregate over multiple rows - you can do as below

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN `18` = 'c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt_18_c FROM badania
```

So, I am using a CASE statement in my sql - which you can find some more info on "[Case statement in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265874/case-statement-in-mysql)". You could also do it differently as a [`SUM(CASE...END)` is synonymous to a `SUM(IF(...))`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732036/mysql-sum-query-with-if-condition) statement.

If you would want to do over multiple columns and rows, then you would just add the individual sums you are interested in like in:

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN `18` = 'c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  + SUM(CASE WHEN `17` = 'c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
  AS cnt_18_17_c FROM badania
```

Different groupings (other than all) can by defined with a `GROUP BY`. If it is row by row - then the SUM is not even needed.

```
SELECT
 CASE WHEN `18` = 'c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
 + CASE WHEN `17` = 'c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
 AS cnt_18_17_c FROM badania
```

in the latter case, you can also user smarter techniques. You could [concatenate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975958/mysql-concatenation) all the tooth as a string, and count occurrences in a string, assuming that the standard set of API's with mysql offers you such a character count. - or you could potentially accomplish the count from within your programming environment (which was PHP). You can also use another [smart way to do those character counts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344795/count-the-number-of-occurences-of-a-string-in-a-varchar-field).

So I gave a couple of examples - hope I got the MySQL syntax right. Not quote sure exactly what you were asking - I suspect I might have covered it here.

Answer (score -1):

The query is making the assumption you want to look at a particular patient and is making a guess at how this is done - adjust accordingly.  Remove the where clause if you want to aggregate all patients.

```
select tooth_code, count(*)
  from ( select 18 as tooth_code from badania where idb=2 and pacjent=25 union all
         select 17 from badania union where idb=2 and pacjent=25 all
         select 16 from badania union where idb=2 and pacjent=25 all
         select 15 from badania union where idb=2 and pacjent=25 all
         select 14 from badania union where idb=2 and pacjent=25 all
         select 13 from badania union where idb=2 and pacjent=25 all
         select 12 from badania union where idb=2 and pacjent=25 all
         select 11 from badania union where idb=2 and pacjent=25 all
         select 21 from badania union where idb=2 and pacjent=25 all
         select 22 from badania union where idb=2 and pacjent=25 all
         select 23 from badania union where idb=2 and pacjent=25 all
         select 24 from badania union where idb=2 and pacjent=25 all
         select 25 from badania union where idb=2 and pacjent=25 all
         select 26 from badania union where idb=2 and pacjent=25 all
         select 27 from badania union where idb=2 and pacjent=25 all
         select 28 from badania union where idb=2 and pacjent=25 all
         select 47 from badania union where idb=2 and pacjent=25 all
         select 46 from badania union where idb=2 and pacjent=25 all
         select 45 from badania union where idb=2 and pacjent=25 all
         select 44 from badania union where idb=2 and pacjent=25 all
         select 43 from badania union where idb=2 and pacjent=25 all
         select 42 from badania union where idb=2 and pacjent=25 all
         select 41 from badania union where idb=2 and pacjent=25 all
         select 31 from badania union where idb=2 and pacjent=25 all
         select 32 from badania union where idb=2 and pacjent=25 all
         select 33 from badania union where idb=2 and pacjent=25 all
         select 34 from badania where idb=2 and pacjent=25 union all
         select 35 from badania where idb=2 and pacjent=25 union all
         select 36 from badania where idb=2 and pacjent=25 union all
         select 37 from badania where idb=2 and pacjent=25 union all
         select 38 from badania where idb=2 and pacjent=25 
       ) 
   group by tooth_code
```